# updating more then 30000+ rows at a time, this process taking 18+ seconds to perform.how can i speed this query up

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code sample that taking too much time to update  30,000+ rows.pleas help me to sort this.it takes more then 18+ second to complete the query.what should i have to do to  speed up query. i am using php and mysql for db.daily 4000+ users are increasing.i am worring about updation issues.i search alot about speed up query but nothing match with my case.

```
function inc_chain_count( $sid )
{
include('connection_file.php');
$select_all = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id
     , green_status
     , chain_count
     , package_choose
     , level
     , level_chain_count
     , daily_cap_achieved 
  FROM member 
 WHERE id < ? 
   and package_choose != 1
");
$select_all->bind_param("i",$sid);
$select_all->execute();
$select_all->bind_result( $all_id, $status, $s_chain_count, $package_choose, $s_level, $l_c_c, $daily_cap );
$ids = [];
while($select_all->fetch())
{
    array_push($ids, array(
        'id' => $all_id,
        'level' => $s_level,
        'chain_count' => $s_chain_count,
        'status' => $status,
        'package_choose' => $package_choose,
        'daily_cap_achieved' => $daily_cap,
        'level_chain_count' => $l_c_c
    ));
}

$select_all->close();

foreach ( $ids as $current_id)
{

    $work = false;
  if($current_id['level'] == 0 && $current_id['status'] == 1 && $current_id['daily_cap_achieved'] < 4) {
    if($current_id['level'] == 0 && $current_id['package_choose'] != 1 ) {

        $work = true;
    }elseif($current_id['level'] == 1 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 1 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 2 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 2 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 3 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 4 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 4 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 6 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 5 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 9 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 6 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 12 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 7 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 17 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 8 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 22 ) {

        $work = true;
    } elseif($current_id['level'] == 9 && $current_id['level_chain_count'] >= 29 ) {

        $work = true;
    }

    if( $current_id['package_choose'] == 1 ){
        $work = false;
    }

    if($work) {

        $chain_inc = $conn->prepare("UPDATE member SET chain_count = chain_count + 1, daily_cap_achieved = daily_cap_achieved + 1 WHERE id = ? ");
        $chain_inc->bind_param('i', $current_id['id']);
        $chain_inc->execute();
        $chain_inc->close();

        $chain = $conn->prepare("SELECT chain_count, level FROM member WHERE id = ?");
        $chain->bind_param('i', $current_id['id']);
        $chain->execute();
        $chain->bind_result($chain_counting, $level_achieved);
        $chain->fetch();
        $chain->close();

        //L E V E L S
        level( $chain_counting, $current_id['id'], $level_achieved );

    }else{
        $chain_inc = $conn->prepare("UPDATE member SET flash_out = flash_out + 1 WHERE id = ? ");
        $chain_inc->bind_param('i', $current_id['id']);
        $chain_inc->execute();
        $chain_inc->close();
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

}

Comment: I don't understand the point of the select

Comment: selection of all users that enter in db first . and increase chain_count colum by 1. becasue one new users registered after them.

Comment: A SELECT is for displaying data to an end user. As far as I can tell, that doesn't happen here, so get rid of it.

Comment: select is needed there.without select users query is incomplete

Comment: Please specify in words what exactly you are trying to achieve. What is in the DB and what is the intended result. Your code is comlicated, I think, but som comments on it might help.

Comment: Do you know if the bottleneck is before or after the SELECT?  To me it looks like the SELECT statement may not find an efficient index.  Additionally, executing 30k separate update queries seems pointless in your case since the update can be achieved in 1 query.  Not sure why you're checking the value of $current_id['package_choose'] === 1 in the foreach since in the query you specified that it cannot equal 1.

Comment: Also, executing 30k individual queries is just generally going to take a long time regardless of how quick each query is.  Better to combine inserts and updates into 1 query when possible, and in your case it is.

Comment: i need to check every user's level(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, upto 10) and need to count referral users by them as level_chain_count. if some one has enough refer and then i need to increase chain_count by one for every users in the db users table.(only for those who has refferral users )

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, doing 30k+ `UPDATE` queries is nearly always going to be slow because of the added overhead of preparing statements, sending them over the network, having them executed by the database, sending those results back to your application, and then parsing the results into a PHP array.

Really what you want to do is cut this down to one or two `UPDATE`s instead.

Instead of using `SELECT` to get all the IDs you'd like to update, and then looping over the results to do extra logic in PHP and then issue an `UPDATE` per ID, we can simply use the `SELECT`'s `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE`.

So here's the strategy:

1) Form a `SELECT` query that selects only the records you want to update. This is a great way to debug your logic because you can run the SQL and see right away whether you're going to be working on the right things

2) Take the `WHERE` clause of that `SELECT` query, and add it to an `UPDATE` query that sets the values you want to set.

Example:

```sql
UPDATE member
SET chain_count = chain_count + 1
  , daily_cap_achieved = daily_cap_achieved + 1
WHERE id < ? -- bound to $sid
and package_choose != 1
and level = 0
and status = 1
and daily_cap_achieved < 4
```

3) Eliminate actually running the `SELECT` query in your code unless you need to further process the data. For instance, I see you `SELECT` the data, loop over the IDs, `UPDATE` each ID, `SELECT` that ID *again* and then run the `levels` function on some of the data.

So your code essentially becomes (since you indicated in a comment that you need to update member's every 75 added to their chain_count):

```php
$chain_inc = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE member 
    SET chain_count = chain_count + 1
      , daily_cap_achieved = daily_cap_achieved + 1 
    WHERE id < ? 
      AND package_choose != 1
      AND level = 0
      AND chain_count % 75 = 0
      AND // any other conditions to only update the ones you need!");

$chain_inc->bind_param('i', $sid);
$chain_inc->execute();
$chain_inc->close();

$flash_out_inc = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE member 
    SET flash_out = flash_out + 1 
    WHERE id < ? 
    AND package_choose == 1
    AND // any other conditions to only update the ones you need!");
$flash_out_inc->bind_param('i', $sid);
$flash_out_inc->execute();
$flash_out_inc->close();

$select_all = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id
     , green_status
     , chain_count
     , package_choose
     , level
     , level_chain_count
     , daily_cap_achieved 
  FROM member 
 WHERE id < ? 
   and package_choose != 1
   and // other conditions that will probably match the conditions from $chain_inc!
");
$select_all->bind_param("i",$sid);
$select_all->execute();

// bind the results, loop over the results, run `levels` etc.
```

Instead you're just running the two `UPDATE`s first, then running an equivalent `SELECT` to get all the newly updated data, and then you can run your `levels` function against the updated data. Three queries instead of 30k+!

Comment: thanks for your efforts daniel.i am checking each users beacause if a user's chain_count is 75 then i increase his level from 0 to 1 and i further check for next user if user's level is 1 and chain_count is 150 then increase level colum to 2. (every 75 new chain_count level increase by one)these are my some conditions that need to fulfill.

Comment: @deepmann I added that condition to the example I gave you to better illustrate the ideas I'm talking about.

Comment: i got your idea. but what if i need to check what users level is, then i increase his level by one when he fulfill certain condition.  SET chain_count = chain_count + 1
      , daily_cap_achieved = daily_cap_achieved + 1 
    WHERE id < ? 
      AND package_choose != 1
      AND level = 0
      AND chain_count % 75 = 0 // here i am only able to check level 0 users only. there are other with level 1 and so on upto 10 level

Comment: That `AND level = 0` was simply based off of your original query, it was just an example. If you wish to select all levels then get rid of that condition. Or add a similar set of conditions that selects the levels you need